# Automatically Email Reports From Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to automatically email reports from Access at a specific time

I really don't have a lot of experience creating macros in Access, but I tried creating a macro that will automatically send an email at a specific time.  This is what it looks like so far:

```
if [time] = "12:00:00 AM" then
emaildatabaseobject
Object Type Report
Object Name NameofReport
Output Format PDF 
To desiredemail@email.com
CC
BCC
Subject test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally suggest using the MS Access Macro to solely perform the emailing operation (either using the [`EmailDatabaseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/emaildatabaseobject-macro-action) action, [`SendObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.sendobject) method of the [`DoCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd) object in VBA, or by automating the installed email client using ActiveX in VBA).

You can then use **Windows Task Scheduler** to invoke the MS Access Macro at a given time or on a given schedule.

To create a Scheduled Task to invoke an MS Access Macro, perform the following steps:

- Open Task Scheduler in Windows either through the Start Menu or by running `taskschd.msc`
- Select the **Task Scheduler Library** from the left-hand pane (or create your own folder beneath this)
- From the right-hand **Actions** pane, select **Create Task**
- Populate the obvious options such as the *Name*, *Description*, etc. as appropriate.
- Add a **Trigger** based on the time/schedule on which you wish to run the macro.
- Add an **Action** and select **Start a Program**
- Browse to the location of and select the `MSACCESS.exe` executable.
- In the **Add arguments** edit box, specify the filepath to your database (enclosed in double quotes if the path contains any spaces), followed by the `/x` command-line switch and the name of your macro, e.g.:

  ```
  "C:\Your Folder\Your Database.accdb" /x YourMacro
  ```

  Or, if you have a SubMacro within the Macro:

  ```
  "C:\Your Folder\Your Database.accdb" /x YourMacro.YourSubMacro
  ```

  You can find out more about the available command-line switches for MS Access [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Access).