# Automate unattended running of an Access module periodically

Tags: ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I have an access database that uses data pulled from an API, this data export is conducted hourly.

I would like the access database to automatically run an update module (which imports the exported data and cleans it up), based on the same schedule the API exports my data, so Access will be current at all times.

The database I designed is used company wide. The accde and backend are both located on a windows 2008 server.

I just wanted suggestions on the best way to automate this, without the need of human intervention, preferably nor my local machine.

From rough research (accompanied by my own ignorance and stupidity) I’m assuming I need to setup a task scheduler on the server to launch access and run the module on open if FOS username is the local machines user (administrator).

I highly welcome any feedback as again, I just taught myself access these past two months and am horribly unknowledgeable on the implementation side.

Comment: Yes, Task Scheduler should be able to open db with switch arguments, however, I use a VBScript that is opened by Task Scheduler.

Comment: You can follow a method similar to that which I have described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707749/7531598) (albeit without the emailing operation).